# MapView Class Not Found error.. Unsure why

Tags: android, exception, google-maps

I have a xml based Relative Layout and was attempting to add a small MapView to the layout,  I obtained an API key (debug),  Changed my platform target from Android 2.2 to the appropriate Google APIs platform, and then added the 'uses-library' code to manifest.

Finally adding in the xml to my relative layout:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="@string/MAPS_API_KEY"
    />
```

I did expect this would be all I need, but when attempting to run (on my plugged in Desire HD) when I launch this activity I receive a class not found exception for the MapView.

So not sure if the issue is related to my particular handset or version of google maps or something I've done wrong..  As this application is intended to eventually be released to the public if using MapViews can be unreliable, then I won't show it and instead have a button that launches the full google maps(if available).

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Does your Activity inherit from `MapActivity`?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Is this a requirement then?  With it being ClassNotFound I'd have thought it's something more to do with the build or classes on my device which are exposed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the location of my 'uses-library' declaration in the manifest.

Usually I place all my uses-permissions etc underneath my activitiy declarations, once I'd moved the uses-library line above the activity declarations, then everything worked as expected.

One to watch out for !!!!!

Thanks guys for you input.

Answer (score 0):

Not being flippant, but you did rebuild the apk after you changed the target platform and then run it on your device? Also, do you have the uses-permissions in your manifest also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Forgot to add, I assume the textview with id 'txAddress' exists in the Relative layout, otherwise you won't see the MapView.

Comment: Yes, Those persmissions are all being used elsewhere in the app and the address is present. The problem is before it tries to generate the view as such as it can't even find the MapView class